# how to fix get data from a model in flask?

Tags: python, linq, flask, model

i am trying to learn working with db models and i am using Flask as a Framework to design web by python. i have a profile page that should get user data from a table named user that has built by a model named User.

when i print user variable it is OK and returns username But i can not get the image.

```
user = models.User.get(models.User.username == a)
#a is a variable filled by session contains username
image=models.User.select(models.User.image).where(models.User.username==user).get()
```

i do not have an Error. Just it always returns None .

Comment: do you have only `username` in `user` ? or maybe you have to use `user.username`  to get only name ?

Comment: my User model has many fields but i need username and image. getting user is ok but i can not get image

Comment: you may have to use `user.username` in `wherer(models.User.username==user.username)` to get `image`

Comment: i have used user.username but it still shows 'None'